# Google Scripts gives syntax error for valid JavaScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the following function to run in a Google Script tied to a Google Sheet. Currently, I'm testing with dummy data and not pulling from the sheet. The below function runs in Chrome, Firefox, and Node, but I get a "Syntax error" and cannot save in the Google script.

```
function tasksToCommands(tasks) {
  var commands = tasks.map((task) => {
    return {
      "type": "item_add",
      "temp_id": randomID(),
      "uuid": randomID(),
      "args": task
    }
  })
  return JSON.stringify(commands)
}
```

Apparently the syntax error on the line with commands, but like I said, it runs everywhere else.

Comment: Because Google Apps Script is not bleeding-edge javascript.... Arrow syntax is not valid

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks! I just figured they'd be using V8 to interpret 2015 JS

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response above, I rewrote the function in ES5 JavaScript and it worked:

```
function yeOldeTasksToCommands(tasks) {
  var yeOldeCommands = tasks.map(function(task) {
    return {
      "type": "item_add",
      "temp_id": randomID(),
      "uuid": randomID(),
      "args": task
    }
  })
  return JSON.stringify(yeOldeCommands)
}
```

Still confused as to why 2015 JavaScript isn't supported in 2019 if anyone has any more info on how `.gs` is interpreted.